# How to change color of circle which is created on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

How to change color of circle which is created on canvas , In detail : created circle on canvas here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new SampleView(this));
}

private static class SampleView extends View {

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        // smooths
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
        p.setStrokeWidth(4.5f);
        // opacity
        //p.setAlpha(0x80); //
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 30, p);
    }

}
}
```

here attaching this canvas to imageview. now how to change the color of this circle on each tap , means for first tap i want red color, 2nd tap need green and third tap back to normal state. how to do this.

Comment: Change `p.setColor(Color.RED);` to another color. i.e.: `p.setColor(Color.GREEN);`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by doing following:

-> have a static variable(`static int DESIRED_COLOR;`)  which can be used to store your desired color code

-> instead of fix, `p.setColor(Color.RED);` use some static variable like: `p.setColor(DESIRED_COLOR);`

-> on every touch, change value of that static variable (`DESIRED_COLOR`) according to your requirements, like: `DESIRED_COLOR = Color.GREEN`

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the solution below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

SampleView mSampleView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mSampleView = new SampleView(this);
    setContentView(mSampleView);
    mSampleView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

private static class SampleView extends View{

    public static int i = 0;
    Paint p;
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        p = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Log.i("i = ", "1");

        canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);

        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        if(i==0)
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        else if (i==1)
            p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        else
            p.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE); 
        p.setStrokeWidth(4.5f);
        canvas.drawCircle(500, 500, 100, p);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    mSampleView.i=(mSampleView.i+1)%3;
    v.invalidate();
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: ,Here if i touch out side the then also ARC color changing,How to apply touch for only arc?

Comment: You can get screen co-ordinates using getX() and getY() command and check if it falls under the arc region and then you can change color. just a "if()" condition.

Comment: i know how to get screen dimensions but didn't get this condition.

Comment: event.getX() and event.getY() will return you touch co-ordinates, then you know the co-ordinates of the circle as you are defining its location(its centre and radius). So, just check if screen co-ordinates falls inside your circle area.